# My web app is really slow on TOR, and unusable on web proxies

Tags: proxy, tor

My AngularJs http://www.applicationsh.fr/geretonequipe/ web app is really slow on TOR , and unusable on some web proxies such as https://www.proxysite.com/fr/

Is this normal ?

I'd like to test it from a USA windows machine with a USA ip, with no proxy, how could i do ?

I have only base64 pics, is this bad ?
The JS encryption makes fails in TOR, what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

TOR have a big encryption and do lot of server jumps. Its normal it have delays.

I dont know how fast is the line on proxysite server, Maybe you can try a private [proxy web](https://proxyseo.es)

Base64 pics increases a little the size of each file so the loading will be a bit slower and can be incompatible with older browsers or obsolete systems I am not known problems with TOR